# Multiple declaration files for a single given library breaking compilation

Tags: typescript

Working on a React project with TypeScript and React Transition Group, I get compilation errors due to TypeScript grabing two different definition files for React.

### Partial list of installed modules:

- `react`
- `react-dom`
- `react-transition-group`
- `@types/react`
- `@types/react-dom`
- `@types/react-transition-group`

### Problem:

I import the `<Transition />` component like so: `import Transition from 'react-transition-group/Transition';`. TypeScript complains, saying `JSX element type 'Transition' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.`

Here's the full error:

`[ts] JSX element type 'Transition' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
[ts]
JSX element type 'Transition' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
 Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
   Type '() => string | number | false | Element | Element[] | null' is not assignable to type '{ (): false | Element | null; (): string | number | false | Element | Element[] | null; (): strin...'.
     Type 'string | number | false | Element | Element[] | null' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.`

### My guess

My component's `import * as React from 'react'` and the `<Transition />` component's `import { Component } from 'react'` don't target the same version of the React declaration file and it causes conflicts.

Would there be a way to force TypeScript to use a specific declaration file for any given import of React?

Comment: Are you using `yarn` or `npm`?  My guess is `yarn`.  There are some issues with `yarn` not properly deduplicating declaration files right now.  https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4489

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be a way to force TypeScript to use a specific declaration file for any given import of React?

All react components should *not* have `@types/react` as a `dependency`. It should only be a `devDependency`. This is the proper fix.

Comment: They don't. Components are importing `import * as React from 'react'`. The third-party component's declaration file (`*.d.ts`) imports `import {Component} from 'react'`. _TypeScript_ resolves those imports to two different `@types/react`.

Comment: They would all resolve the the same `@types/react` if the component only had it as a `devDependency`.

Comment: Right, I get what you're saying, but seeing as I can't control their `package.json`, this isn't really an answer I can use...